# How to identify which Button was pressed

Tags: python, kivy

In Kivy, when creating a button instance, you can bind that button to an event, say like this:

```
btn = Button( text='This do be a button' )
btn.bind( on_release=self.method_call )
self.add_widget( btn )
```

And if you want to create a lot of buttons, say an arbitrary amount based on a bunch of strings in a list, you might do:

```
list = ('item1', 'item2', 'item3', 'item4')
for item in list:
    self.btn = Button( text=item )
    #some method call
    self.add_widget( btn )
```

How can you call a method and pass some identifier for the button for each unique button press?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The callback function you pass to the `bind` call will receive a reference to the pressed `Button` instance as an argument when it is called.

So, to tell what button it is, you just need to keep all your buttons around somewhere and compare against them or perhaps extract the `text` you're setting as the button's label, depending on what exactly you want to do with the result.

So, the code you need to change is in `self.method`, not in the code setting up the button (except if you want to keep the button objects around for some reason, you probably want to be appending them to a list, rather than repeatedly overwriting `self.button`).